# How to connect Jupyter Notebook Remote Server on AWS- Ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to setup a remote Jupyter Notebook server on an AWS Ubuntu machine. 
I followed this blog: http://blog.impiyush.me/2015/02/running-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws.html

I'm able to do a `wget` on the server and get the html. However when I try from my laptop browser i get a Connection Timed Out message.

I thought it may be a port issue for port 8888 (on which my notebook server is configured.

So I did `sudo ufw allow 8888`. Doing `netstat` shows that python is listening to all IPs on the port:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1833/python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting here for future reference.

Found the issue. The AWS Security Group settings were not configured to allow incoming connections on either HTTPS (443) or 8888. I added those rules in to the AWS console and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to  `Inbound` settings, change rules, below rules worked for me !

[image]